# A book with tentacled natives, on a planet visited by Earthmen

Tags: story-identification, books, space

I recall a book, probably that I read in the 1960s, featuring
peaceful interaction between star-faring humans and an
intelligent tentacled race.

The scene that sticks in my mind was a tour of a factory
where an alien operated a machine tool, with
a tentacle draped on each of the many levers and cranks,
and could whip out complex parts in a few seconds.

The humans couldn't match that performance, but the
aliens were incapable of operating a typewriter keyboard: 
tentacles aren't good at tapping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is "Overproof" by "Jonathan Blake MacKenzie".  It appeared in 
*Analog Science Fact-Science Fiction* in the October 1965 issue.  I quoted MacKenzie, as this was a pseudonym of Randall Garrett.

The basic plot is that a couple of anthropologists come to Sandaroth, which is a mixed human-Daroth colony planet to investigate reports of abuse of the humanoid natives. The Daroth -- described at one point as tentacled tiger-sharks -- prove to be alien, but humane, and the joint colony seems to be working very well.

The accusation is that the Daroth treat the humanoid natives as animals, including eating them.  The anthropologists -- bumbling fools as anthropologists in *Analog* tended to be -- are convinced that the natives are intelligent, because they look like especially beautiful Terrans.  Events prove them wrong.

There is a major scene where one of the anthropologists gets a demonstration of the astonishing machining skills a coordinated, eight-tentacled, intelligent creature has.  I can't find the bit about typewriters in a quick scan through the story (though I remember reading it), but in the machine shop segment, the Daroth mentions that they are no good at engraving because they can't push the burin.

Comment: Yep, that sounds like it.   Probably I read it about 1970... in library bound periodocals.   I'll try to find it elsewhere (will search anthologies)